# LinearLayout.LayoutParams how to use dip...?

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the height of my `LinearLayout` to 45 dip.

How can I do this when extending `LinearLayout`?

Right now I just did: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 45);`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The best way to go for this kind of issue is create a `dimens.xml` file under values and put in your dip values there, and then in code you pull the dimensions from that file. That's what resources are for, right? =)

Here's an example of a `dimens.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="about_image_bottom">0dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And this is how you can pull it out in code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iv_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
iv_params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.about_image_bottom));
```

And then you set the parameters to whatever object you need, in my case to the ImageView iv:

```
iv.setLayoutParams(iv_params);
```

Comment: Shouldn't dimens.xml contains dimen in dip instead of dp? As dip is much more precise...

Comment: dip == dp, if you check the answer here, they have all the information about what the different units of measurement mean in Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: Great flawless solution :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use `DisplayMatrics` and determine the screen density. Something like this:

```
int pixelsValue = 5; // margin in pixels
float d = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int margin = (int)(pixelsValue * d);
```

Hope it helps ^^

Answer (score -1):

Probably the best way would be to specify it in XML.  Replace the normal LinearLayout tag with what ever class you created to extend the LinearLayout in the XML tag:

```
<com.example.MyLinearLayout 
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="45dp" 
              android:orientation="vertical" >
 ....
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_height) for more info.